# swift/spritekit/tilemap: how to rotate single tile?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have (programmatically) created a `tilemap` in SpriteKit, I can check if a tile has been tapped and i can get the row and the col of the tile within the `tileset`.

but I cannot get the tile to be rotated or flipped etc.

Here is my code in `touchesEnded` where i handle this:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(location)
    
    if let name = touchedNode.name
    {
        let tempRow = tileMap.tileRowIndex(fromPosition: location)
        let tempCol = tileMap.tileColumnIndex(fromPosition: location)
        let tile = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: tempCol, row: tempRow)

        tile!.rotation = SKTileDefinitionRotation.rotation90
        tile!.size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
        
    } else {
//      print("no name found!")
    }
}
```

in override func `didMove` I have defined the `tileMap`:

```
var tileMap = SKTileMapNode()
tileMap = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet, columns: colums, rows: rows, tileSize: tileSize)
```

I can see the `tileMap` with the correct tiles showing up, i can tap them, but they do not rotate or flip or change size

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't believe you can change this directly, if you check the documentation for SKTileMapNode, we can read that "A tile map can only render tile definitions that exist within the SKTileSet you have provided it.". What I take from this is that when you rotate a specific tile this new configuration ceases to exist in your SKTileSet, so it won't get rendered.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so you think that i cannot rotate a single tile within a tilemap (and all tile positions do not change; only 90 degreee rotation of one tile)? That would be bad, because it limits the tileSet - but maybe those tileSets are more likely used as a map oder background and not as tiles to interact like a pipe game or a 3-match game...